# What's the difference between DBR versions with and without LTS?

Tags: databricks

I am aware that DBR versions with LTS are fully supported for 2 years, while DBR versions without are supported for 6 months only.

Apart from this, are there any other differences I should be aware of before deciding on a DBR version?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support time is the primary difference between LTS & non-LTS versions.

Usually, non-LTS versions released after LTS version contain new functionality, performance improvements, etc., so you can benefit from them.

What I typically see working with customers, people tend to follow following patterns:

- LTS versions - use for production jobs, etc., making sure that they are on supported version and not required to do upgrade every half year.
- non-LTS versions - use to evaluate new functionality, prepare for upgrades, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this was really clear and makes total sense!